# Store statistical data with decreasing precision over time

Tags: mysql, statistics

Is there a special data-format, approach or best-practise to store data e.g. in a mysql database with decreasing accuracy over time?

Imagine I would like to display the number of pageviews on a site with

- an hourly precision for the last 24h
- an daily precision for the last 7 days
- an weekly precision for the last X months

and so on...

[Nagios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagios) seems to have something like this build in: you can zoom into charts at any time without really noticing a poor distribution of data points.

Of course I could simply store it detailed for all times and simply aggregate via GROUP BY but I am looking for a good trade-off regarding the amount of data I have to store and the option to inspect the trend over time.

Are there any strategies regarding this? What do I have to search for in Google? I can't find anything maybe I am missing some keyword to include.

Answer (score 0):

There are several strategies in this, try and search for "time-series database". You will find multiple results on how to implement this yourself, or use databases specially designed for this type of data:

- [InfluxDB](http://influxdb.com/)
- [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net/)
- [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) (Not really a time-series database, but you could modify your setup and application code to make it work like one, I do this myself actually.

Answer (score 0):

[RRDtool](http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/) was built especially with the goal of storing time series with decreasing precision efficiently. Several system monitoring tools are using it for storing performance data.